# It can be happened.. is it false to utter it?

Tags: expressions

is it wrong to use this expression " It can be happened...". In fact many of colleagues said that the right expression is " It can happen". Do you have any comments on this?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Whether a statement is true or false depends on the situation and has nothing to do with the statement being a correct English sentence (which your example is not). Maybe your question will feel better at home at our sister site: [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction you propose, “It can be happened,” is a passive one, and only transitive verbs can have passives. (The passive voice is a transformation whereby the verb’s direct object becomes its subject, and only transitive verbs, by definition, have direct objects.) And the only transitive sense listed for *happen* in the OED is listed as “Chiefly *Eng. regional (north.)”* and “Now *rare.”* (The examples given for this sense have for its direct objects such words as *mischance, adventure,* or *accident.)* So with that extremely marginal exception, no, the proposed construction is not grammatical in English.